# Protocol handler initialization failed:

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

Hi when i try to start my Tomcat 6.0 i got such error,

so can  u give me some solution for this one

```
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Java/jre6/bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Java\jdk1.5\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Liquid Technologies\Liquid XML Studio 2009\XmlDataBinder7\Redist7\cpp\win32\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8081
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getStore
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati/.keystore due to C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:269)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:419)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:269)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:419)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
SEVERE: Catalina.start
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 506 ms
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8081
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getStore
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati/.keystore due to C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:269)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:419)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:347)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:269)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:419)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay.prajapati\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1094)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Mar 9, 2011 5:29:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 302 ms
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the error for tomcat keystore, all you need to do is to **remove** the entry below from server.xml

relevant links to manage SSL configuration [links](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-ssl-howto.html#s6)

Syntax for Tomcat 3.2 :

```
<Connector className="org.apache.tomcat.service.PoolTcpConnector"> 
<Parameter name="handler" value="org.apache.tomcat.service.http.HttpConnectionHandler"/> 
<Parameter name="port" value="8443"/> 
<Parameter name="socketFactory" value="org.apache.tomcat.net.SSLSocketFactory" /> 
<Parameter name="keystore" value="/var/tomcat/conf/keystore" /> 
<Parameter name="keypass" value="mynewpass"/> 
<Parameter name="clientAuth" value="false"/> 
</Connector>
```

Syntax for Tomcat 3.3 :

```
<Http10Connector 
  port="8443" 
  secure="true" 
  keystore="/var/tomcat/conf/keystore" 
  keypass="mynewpass" 
  clientauth="false" />
```

restart tomcat it shouldnot show the error

Answer (score 12):

For me the protocol handler initialization failed was caused by "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind".
To fix it I had to run command prompt as administrator.
Since I was trying to run on port 8080 I typed the following command:

`netstat -ano | findStr 8080`

[image]
This showed that the port was in fact in use. I then used the following to kill the task and clear the port:

`TaskKill.exe /F /PID 24216`

This killed the task and I was able to run my intellij on port 8080 again.

Answer (score 5):

For Tomcat 7.x and above add the 'keystoreFile' and 'keystorePass' attributes to the SSL connector definition within your [Tomcat-Home]/conf/server.xml file as the following:

```
    <Connector port="8443" 
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           SSLEnabled="true" 
           maxThreads="150" 
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" 
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="C:\cert\myTomcatKeytool.jks"  
           keystorePass="123456"
           />
```

You should generate a  .jks file by open_ssl tool or keytool.exe (located in your java/bin folder).
Google it to find out how to. 
(Y. Lev)

Answer (score 1):

> **org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed**

change server.port=8080  Ex. server.port=8000

Comment: It worked for me. weird solution but do you have any idea why this worked?